# Unable to run empty ASP.Net MVC 3 Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-web-developer-2010

I have installed:

- Visual Web Developer 2010 Express
- [ASP.Net MVC 3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1491)

I went to **File** > **New Project** > **ASP.Net MVC 3 Web Application**

I chose **Empty** template with **ASPX** view engine. VWD generated lots of files.

When I clicked **Run**, I get the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily  unavailable. Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /
>
> ---
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1

What am I missing here? Is there something else that needs to be done to get it running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's true

An empty application doesn't have a single controller or view defined. It's all on you. Most people start with an application.

Comment: Oh! With all the src files that were generated, I thought *something* would show up. I'll look up some samples on the net and try to add some controller/view to the application. Thanks!

Comment: I can see why you'd think that. But it really is "empty". No Controller, No View. All customizable.